# Tuleap - Cannot create report

Tags: report, tuleap

I have installed Tuleap 7.9 on a CentOS6 virtual machine. I have succeed to create a new projet, and I tried to installed the Agile dashboard.

The problem is that I can't create a new Report on the Tracker tab. I can click on the '+' and set a new name, but when I click on 'Validate', the new report tab is not created. (for an agile dashboard, or simple table, etc.)

I have installed Tuleap 7.11(.99.45) from scratch and I still have the same problem. It may come from my CentOS configuration ? Any rights problem on a directory or something like this ? Do you have any idea ?

I have opened a request on tuleap : https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=7921

Regards,

Comment: I have the same problem with the newest version of Tuleap.
Version 8.0.99.80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case, the problem was due to rights management.
By default, SELinux is configured as '*enforcing*', and it must be modified. To check what is your current configuration, use the command:

```
getenforce
```

The value must be '*permissive*'. If it's not the case, use the following command to modify it :

```
setenforce 0
```

Or, to change it definitely, change the content of the file :

```
/etc/sysconfig/selinux
```